# Incompatible pixel format YUV420P with mjpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, multimedia, mjpeg

I am using ffmpeg to make a video from jpeg images using mjpeg codec.
I use this command

```
ffmpeg -i frame%d.jpg -c:v mjpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -q:v 1 -y out.mp4
```

and I have this warning the yuvj420p was chosen instead. After reading about that pixel format, I found its deprecated to use YUV420p and set the -color_range.
So I did so and set the color_range to 2, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the warning because ffmpeg's internal JPEG encoder expects JPEG-range input, and does so using the old (deprecated) pixfmt YUVJ420P instead of the new method (setting pixfmt=YUV420P with color-range).

However, that brings us to the core of this question: why are you re-encoding JPEG source images to JPEG? You don't need to! You can just use -c:v copy (instead of -c:v mjpeg) to copy the existing JPEG images as-is into the .mp4 file.

Comment: I want to get the highest quality video for later use, so does using the copy is better than encoding?

Comment: Well, yes, because you will never get better than the original. The output will only ever be so good as the input, never better, often worse, sometimes far worse. The trade-off between quality/bitrate may be better if you re-encode (that's what JPEG optimizers do, for example), but the quality won't be different. If you want to re-encode in the same codec at the same quality but better quality/bitrate trade-off, consider using -sameq.

Comment: Even "-v:copy" can produce "Unsupported Pixel Format" with ffmpeg. This happened with an "yuvj444p" input.